# Packaging Error when attempting to package Unreal Engine 4.23 with Chaos enabled

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am receiving some type of packaging error when attempting to package my project. It occurs when compiling one of the ThirdParty plugins within the engine. I did not modify any engine files so I am not sure why I am getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): Target Platform -- Win64
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): Writing manifest to C:\Source\depot\UnrealEngine-4.23\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Manifest.xml
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): Using Visual Studio 2019 14.24.28314 toolchain (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314) and Windows 10.0.18362.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): Building 3 actions with 12 processes...
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): [1/3] Module.MeshSolverUtilities.cpp
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): C:\Source\depot\UnrealEngine-4.23\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Eigen\Eigen\src/Core/util/Memory.h(73): error C4834: discarding return value of function with 'nodiscard' attribute
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): Took 8.1117657s to run UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=5
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): UnrealBuildTool failed. See log for more details. (C:\Source\depot\UnrealEngine-4.23\Engine\Programs\AutomationTool\Saved\Logs\UBT-CastleFight-Win64-Development.txt)
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=5 (5)
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details from the log file you mention?

`UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): UnrealBuildTool failed. See log for more details. (C:\Source\depot\UnrealEngine-4.23\Engine\Programs\AutomationTool\Saved\Logs\UBT-CastleFight-Win64-Development.txt)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild Programs>AutomationTool or entire solution